# Is zend allows to pass control to a file program which is located outside the zend folder?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Is zend allows to pass control to a file program which lies outside the zend folder and get the control back after finishing the exicution of the program???

I want to access a file program which is located in another sdk(aws sdk: amazone dynamo Db) to access the data to zend frame work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard PHP functions like [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Pay attention to [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) & [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd) too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But what i want is 'i need to pass the control to the new function which lies in some other folder(SDK)'.
Here,
It takes the code and does the execution from the parent program.In effect it cannot use the sdk file supports and credentials.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. ZF is just PHP, so there's no reason that you can't call a function in another library. I use FPDF within ZF websites with no problems.